# React suggestions in VS Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up VS Code so that it suggests me methods that are available on a given import as in this image:

[image: See image]

I have tried NPM intellisense, but after trying it out it does not seem to be it.

Comment: I can't see any extension that is called just "Intellisense"

Comment: Of which language/framework do you need code completion?

Comment: This shouldn't require any plugin to work with js.

Comment: I need this to work in javascript for dependencies.

Comment: According to vs code documentation: `Automatic type acquisition requires npmjs, the Node.js package manager, which is included with the Node.js runtime. `. Do you have npm installed ?

Comment: Yes, I do have that installed.